# ERROR: Could not build wheels for spidev, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects Error: process returned with code 1

Tags: python, spi, raspberry-pi-pico

I've been trying to install spidev to use some new parts I picked up, keep running into this error:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\python.exe" -m pip --disable-pip-version-check --no-color install --no-warn-script-location --user --user --upgrade mcp3008==1.0.0
Collecting mcp3008==1.0.0
  Using cached mcp3008-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Collecting spidev
  Using cached spidev-3.6.tar.gz (11 kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Installing backend dependencies: started
  Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
Building wheels for collected packages: spidev
  Building wheel for spidev (pyproject.toml): started
  Building wheel for spidev (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  Ã— Building wheel for spidev (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  â”‚ exit code: 1
  â•°â”€> [20 lines of output]
      C:\Users\sasha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hsttcn2i\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:745: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: Invalid dash-separated options
      !!
      
              ********************************************************************************
              Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future
              versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead.
      
              By 2023-Sep-26, you need to update your project and remove deprecated calls
              or your builds will no longer be supported.
      
              See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html for details.
              ********************************************************************************
      
      !!
        opt = self.warn_dash_deprecation(opt, section)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'spidev' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for spidev
Failed to build spidev
ERROR: Could not build wheels for spidev, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
Error: process returned with code 1
```

I've tried upgrading pip, pip3, python, microsoft vs, nothing has changed yet...

Comment: The error message is telling you that Visual C++ version 14.0 or greater is needed.

Comment: So how do I fix the error if I've already updated visual C++?

Comment: Apparently you haven't (properly). But otherwise I don't know.